# Sorting a dictionary by highest value of nested list

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict = {a:[2, 4, 5], b:[4, 6, 7], c:[3, 1, 1]}
```

Using the above as an example, how would I sort and print this dict so It displayed as :

```
>>>sorthighest(dict)
b : 7
a : 5
c : 3
```

I'm pretty sure the way to go about this is by doing something along the lines of `max(dict[i])` in a `for:` loop but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Do you want only highest values in your output, our you want to keep the remaining part as well somewhere?

Comment: @bereal just the highest values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the name `dict`, it will shadow the builtin dictionary. You can create a dictionary mapping your orignal keys to the maximum value of the sublists:

```
>>> d_max = {k:max(d[k]) for k in d}
>>> d_max
{'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 7}
```

And then iterate over the sorted items of that dictionary:

```
>>> for k, v in sorted(d_max.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
...     print('{} : {}'.format(k,v))
... 
b : 7
a : 5
c : 3
```

*edit*: If you never need the `d_max` dictionary in order to look up the max values, we can simplify a little further:

```
>>> for k,v in sorted(((max(d[k]), k) for k in d), reverse=True): 
...     print('{} : {}'.format(v,k))
... 
b : 7
a : 5
c : 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in sorted(dict, key= lambda x: max(dict[x]), reverse=True):
    print(i,max(dict[i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are unordered. To create an ordered dictionary use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) as follows:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'a': [2,4,5], 'b': [4,6,7], 'c': [3,1,1]}
modified = {k: max(v) for k, v in d.items()}
answer = OrderedDict(sorted(modified.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
OrderedDict([('b', 7), ('a', 5), ('c', 3)])
```

You can then easily iterate over your *ordered* dictionary as follows:

```
for k, v in answer.items():
    print('{} : {}'.format(k, v))
```

**Output**

```
b : 7
a : 5
c : 3
```